# Universal Image Loader throws UnsupportedOperationException. Who can tell me why

Tags: android

```
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751): UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [><a class=]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [><a class=]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:206)
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:95)
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:340)
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:307)
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:249)
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:131)
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-05 13:29:26.916: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751): UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [><a class=]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [><a class=]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:206)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:95)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:340)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:307)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:249)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:131)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-05 13:29:26.926: E/ImageLoader(6751):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Who can tell me why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is because you gave it a fragment of HTML, not a URL. But [you need to post the actual code that is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481831/universal-image-loader-throws-unsupportedoperationexception-who-can-tell-me-why#comment25406638_17481831).

Comment: As you said, I thank you very much for your help.